# Why might my page suddenly jump (scroll) halfway after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

For some reason, on the home page of my Drupal 7 website, it suddenly jumps halfway down the page, I assume, once the page is ready.  FYI there is no anchor called in the URL...

Anyway I can determine what is causing this?  A way of intercepting the scroll method for example?

Many thanks

Comment: is your site in live?

Comment: Can you please share the url? OR is there any javascript written for that?

Comment: No, it's not currently live

Comment: sounds browser cache'y to me

Comment: maybe <body onload="moveWindow()"> is present on the page with a predefined anchor. can you please post your code? thank you

Comment: Have you got any javascript on the page?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibles:

**scrollTo()**

If you trigger js that contains `scrollTo('some-selector')` then the page will scroll to that position

**focus**

If you have an input on the page that is set to be focused on load, perhaps `<input type='text' name='some-input' autofocus />` then the page load with that input within the viewport

Comment: Look down! He answered his own question and it was none of the above. Caching!

Comment: @JayMoy ... look at the question title and wording, who else might find the problem?